# Apex Trigger to send email with attachment getting a redirect page instead

Tags: apex, trigger, pdf

I have an apex trigger:

```
trigger ConsignmentOrderPDFTrigger on Consignment_Order_Request__c (after insert) {
    for(Consignment_Order_Request__c c : Trigger.New) {
        PDFCreator.generatePDFAttachment(c.Id, c.Name);
    }
}
```

that fires when a custom object is created and makes a call to this function:

```
global class PDFCreator {
    @future
    public static void generatePDFAttachment(Id id, String name) {
        PageReference p = Page.Consignment_Order_PDF_Page;
        p.getParameters().put('id', (String)id);
        p.setRedirect(true);

        Blob b = p.getContent();

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
        efa.setContentType('application/pdf');

        efa.setBody(b);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage e = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        e.setSubject('Consignment Order for ' + name);
        e.setToAddresses(new String[] {'me@mail.com'});
        e.setPlainTextBody('Please process the attached order.');
        e.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { efa });
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { e });
    }
}
```

When I run this code as an anonymous function, everything works and it sends an email with a proper pdf attachment.  However, when I create a new object the pdf sent contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

<script>
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://sandbox.cs18.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsandbox--c.cs18.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252Fconsignment_order_pdf_page%253Fid%253Da0I110000001iLXEAY%2526inline%253D1'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://sandbox.cs18.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsandbox--c.cs18.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252Fconsignment_order_pdf_page%253Fid%253Da0I110000001iLXEAY%2526inline%253D1');
} else {;
window.location.href ='https://sandbox.cs18.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsandbox--c.cs18.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252Fconsignment_order_pdf_page%253Fid%253Da0I110000001iLXEAY%2526inline%253D1';
} 
</script>

</head>
</html>

<!--
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
-->
```

This appears to be a redirect.  I'm guessing it may have something to do with permissions of the process running this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if you have Consignment_Order_PDF_Page in the *Enabled Visualforce Page Access* of the profile's user who is inserting the record?

Comment: I believe the PageReference.getContent method is not supported on @future context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page is not redirected to anywhere. It is showing static visualforce page state.

You have set a visualforce page as a Pagereference. And it has parameter `Id`.
Now you are trying to getContent of it. In this case `p.getContent()` will only retrieve Visualforce page state without firing its constructor.

Constructor never fired by using `getContent()` in triggers and other background processes. Even if page is rendered as "PDF" etc.

In case if constructor get fired you will receive `Null Pointer Exception` because of `ApexPages.currentPage()`

> From the reference: [getContent()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm)
>
> This method can't be used in:
>
> - Triggers
> - Scheduled Apex
> - Batch jobs
> - Test methods
> - Apex email services